# How to block AnonymoX addon operations with Watchguard XTM

Tags: proxy, watchguard, anonymous

We are using Watchguard XTM 502 as firewall in our office. Some of our employee using AnonymoX addon proxy on firefox. Normally Watchguard XTM block proxy. But Watchguard XTM 502 can't able to block AnonymoX.

Here how can i block AnonymoX addon operations ?

** Please improve my question if there are any mistakes.

Comment: I understand you want to block it, but this also sounds like an HR problem as much as a tech one. Time to revisit the acceptable use policy.

Comment: @DanBig HR team requested us to block it by Firewall. I've googled lot.. but can't find solution for it.

Comment: I assume you have a LiveSecurity contract with WG? Call them.

Comment: @DanBig I got following response from Watchguard forum,
add a DNS proxy -> Query Names entry for: 
Pattern Match 
*.anonymox.net 
set to Deny & Log
Move this entry to the top of the list. But it's not working for me.

Comment: Couple of questions - What your clients using as their DNS server? Do you have ANY rules in place for the DNS traffic?